# Laravel get table row values

Tags: php, html, laravel

I need help on getting the email value of the specific row that I selected. For example i selected the 3rd row button, then I will be able to get the value of the 3rd row email.

```
<table class="table  table-striped">
    @foreach($users as $user)
        <tr>
            <td class="col-md-2">
                {!! $user->id !!}
            </td>
            <td class="col-md-2">
                {!! $user->name !!}
            </td>
            <td class="col-md-2">
                <input type="hidden" value="{!! $user->email !!}"> {!! $user->email !!}
            </td>
            <td class="col-md-3">
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-md" value="GET VALUE">
            </td>
        </tr>
    @endforeach
</table>
```

Controller Code

```
public function getData(){
        return var_dump($_POST);
}
```

Whats happening now is whenever I click the button, I always get the email of the last row of the table. Any Idea how to do this guys?

Comment: It seems that you have lot of email address, but you are using same hidden fields, So you must create the Dynamic hidden fields Or you should Assign the email address to a checkbox value, so in this case, whenever you click at checkbox you will receive the selected checked box value

Answer (score 1):

```
            <table class="table  table-striped">
                    @foreach($users as $user)
                      <form method="POST" action="your_controller_function_route">
                        <tr>
                            <td class="col-md-2">
                                    {!! $user->id !!}
                            </td>
                            <td class="col-md-2">
                                     {!! $user->name !!}
                            </td>
                            <td class="col-md-2">
                                <input type="hidden" name="email" value="{!! $user->email !!}"> {!! $user->email !!}
                            </td>
                            <td class="col-md-3">
                                <input type="submit" id ="sub{{ $user->id }}" class="btn btn-success btn-md" value="GET VALUE">
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </form>
                    @endforeach
                </table>
```

try this

Comment: Got the same advise from other but when I did this the submit button no longer works. :(

Comment: solution still not working though. But I based my code on yours so i put the Form tag inside the < td > and its working now. though not the best approach from my point of view. thanks

Answer (score 1):

I got this conclusion as I understood

Try this. My demo for you is work in this way

```
<table class="table  table-striped">
            @foreach($users as $user)
            <form method="POST" name="email{!! $user->id !!}" action="function_to_print_data">
                <tr>
                    <td class="col-md-2">
                        {!! $user->id !!}
                    </td>
                    <td class="col-md-2">
                        {!! $user->name !!}
                    </td>
                    <td class="col-md-2">
                        <input type="hidden" name="email" value="{!! $user->email !!}"> {!! $user->email !!}
                    </td>
                    <td class="col-md-3">
                        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-md" value="GET VALUE">
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </form>
            @endforeach
        </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap each user table row with a form of its own. If not then the last row will overwrite the previous others since every user is wrapped in a single form.

Answer (score 0):

I cant get the form outside the < tr >. If i do the button submit is not working. I was able to make it work by putting it inside the < td >

```
                 <table class="table  table-striped">
                        @foreach($users as $user)
                            <tr>
                                <td class="col-md-2">
                                    {!! $user->id !!}
                                </td>
                                <td class="col-md-2">
                                    {!! $user->name !!}
                                </td>
                                <td class="col-md-2">
                                    {!! $user->email !!}
                                </td>
                                <td class="col-md-3">
                                     <form method="POST" action="/users/getData"> 
                                        <input type="hidden" name="email" value="{!! $user->email !!}">
                                        <input id= "{!! $user->email !!}" type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-md" value="GET VALUE">
                                        {{ csrf_field() }}
                                     </form>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        @endforeach
                    </table>
```

But i dont think this is the best approach for the form. But now its working this way.